# How should I understand this line? (-this.width)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need some help for understand this topic.

I have a canvas element, which represents a background in movement on the 'X' axis, in this way:

```
if(this.x < -this.width) this.x = 0;    
ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
ctx.drawImage(this.img,this.x + this.width, this.y, this.width,this.height);
```

So, How should I read the first line (-this.width)? What does a negative 'this.width' represent and how it work?

Thanks!

Comment: This simply clips any `this.x` to 0 or above. `this.x` will equal `this.width` so long as `this.width` is positive and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It simply checking the value by making it inverse of the original value. That means if it is -1 it will make it 1 or vice verse.

Answer (score 0):

This basically ensures that both images are showing (the first one can be shown partially). So for example you have the following options:

1. this.x is positive or more than this.width (ie x = 20, width = 100). This will draw the first image from px-s 20 to 120 and the next one from 120 to 220 on the X axis.
2. this.x is negative, but not less than -this.width (ie x = -20, width = 100). This will draw the first image from px-s -20 to 80 and the second one from 80 to 180. As you can see 20px width from the image will not be shown on the canvas.
3. this.x is negative and less than the negative value of this.width ie (x = -120, width = 100). This will draw the first image from -120px to -20px and the second one from -20px to 80px. This will completely hide the first image and show the second with 20px width trimmed.

Basically your line of code covers the 3rd option ensuring that you don't end up with the first image off canvas. Not sure why you should settle with one of the images being trimmed, I would set X to 0 if X is negative

Hopefully the following JSfiddle makes it a bit clearer. https://jsfiddle.net/8yzg9b5e/8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

</body>
```